# How to search Twitter for replies to @abc<MY-STRING>def?

Tags: twitter

What's the simplest way, if any, to search Twitter for replies to any username that includes <*string*>?

eg, how to search at the same time for replies to @google, @googletech, @firstgooglers, @nogoogle ?

I'm not a competent developer with any language but I can handle some easy JS or PHP or regex & Bash scripting...snippets welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read through Twitter's search documentation: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search

And then searching for a string, or multiple strings, is easy enough:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@google
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@google+OR+@googletech
```

You can also substitute ".json" for ".atom".

Comment: This way you're searching for mentions, which is something a little bit different than replies: https://support.twitter.com/articles/14023-what-are-replies-and-mentions

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are no official docs on how to do the query strings. But if you use Twitter advanced search and the field "To these accounts", you'll end up with something like to%3Agoogle. It works on the API as well:
    http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=to%3Agoogle

and I'm getting less results than with q=@google .. so I guess it might be right.